# Nginx Ingress on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, bitnami

`I had a working Ingress controller version 1.0.0 (Bitnami). It stopped working one fine morning, and it appeared that the error was due to the version being depricated. Now I tried to upgrade this version, but started getting errors. I delete ingress and reinstalled it again, and this time from Bitnami repo which pulled the latest image. It is throwing errors. I created a new AKS cluster and installed ingress on it from the same repo, and it seems to work perfectly fine. Can somebody help me understand how this can be fixed please? I have over 120 services running on this cluster, and starting over would mean a lot of effort and time.

```css
E0419 10:57:29.245933       1 queue.go:130] "requeuing" err="\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nError: exit status 1\n2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the \"http2_max_field_size\" directive is obsolete, use the \"large_client_header_buffers\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:143\nnginx: [warn] the \"http2_max_field_size\" directive is obsolete, use the \"large_client_header_buffers\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:143\n2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the \"http2_max_header_size\" directive is obsolete, use the \"large_client_header_buffers\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:144\nnginx: [warn] the \"http2_max_header_size\" directive is obsolete, use the \"large_client_header_buffers\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:144\n2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the \"http2_max_requests\" directive is obsolete, use the \"keepalive_requests\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:145\nnginx: [warn] the \"http2_max_requests\" directive is obsolete, use the \"keepalive_requests\" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:145\n2022/04/19 10:57:29 [emerg] 25#25: \"location\" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783\nnginx: [emerg] \"location\" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783\nnginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911 test failed\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" key="initial-sync"
I0419 10:57:29.246021       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"nginx-ingress", Name:"nginx-nginx-ingress-controller-5575846679-bjwkp", UID:"9e5641ae-345c-4d3c-a840-83c143f07fd3", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5932936", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'RELOAD' Error reloading NGINX: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the "http2_max_field_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:143
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_field_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:143
2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the "http2_max_header_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:144
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_header_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:144
2022/04/19 10:57:29 [warn] 25#25: the "http2_max_requests" directive is obsolete, use the "keepalive_requests" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:145
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_requests" directive is obsolete, use the "keepalive_requests" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:145
2022/04/19 10:57:29 [emerg] 25#25: "location" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911 test failed
```

Comment: The error is not related to deprecation but to a syntax error in your config: `"location" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911:783
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg2573211911 test failed`

Comment: Hi Blender Fox, I deployed the exact same image onto a brand new cluster, and it seems to run fine! Moreover, I attempted to login to the pod and change the directive as per the error, but the pod keeps restarting and am unable to complete this task.

Comment: You may have deployed the same image, but the mounted config is likely to be different, hence the different behaviour

Comment: I am sorry, but I a noob at this and I am unsure where I need to fix the config error. To give a context, I have deployed ingress controller as a pod on my AKS cluster. Any direction on how to get this done please?

Comment: Are you using Helm to deploy the ingress controller?

Comment: Yes, helm and bitnami nginx

Comment: Please add the `helm` command line args you used to install the chart (especially any `--set` args, and your `values.yaml` if you specified `--values` with the `helm install` or `helm upgrade`. This will allow us to try to replicate your install and possibly reproduce your version

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with the ingress class name "nginx". I re-deployed the  ingress controller, this time with a values file and ingressclass name as dev-nginx and this seems to resolve the issue. I then had to delete the existing ingressClass and re-deploy ingress to fix the issue.

```css
E0421 07:40:56.183407       7 main.go:122] Unexpected error searching IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io "nginx" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-nginx" cannot get resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
W0421 07:40:56.183431       7 main.go:125] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be us
```